# Ubuntu 22.04. Dash to Panel extension flagged as "Outdated"

Tags: 22.04

Just upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04. The Dash to Panel extension is flagged as "Outdated". How do I get Dash to Panel working?

I removed purged the Firefox Snap and installed deb Firefox. The gnome.extensions icon is in my Firefox extensions bar.

Comment: Dash-to-Panel **version 50** seems up-to-date in my 22.04 system.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I uninstalled Gnome Extensions from Firefox, rebooted and reinstalled it. But the Dash to Panel web page was still greyed out. I was frustrated so I clicked a bunch of times on the greyed out "Outdated" button and suddenly Dash to Panel installed. Huh? Anyway, now it's working fine. (shrug) My solution was the equivalent of just angrily smacking an old tube TV to get it working. Go figure.

Comment: ?  Add the extension on Firefox, can you be more precise and step by step?

Comment: @mLstudent33 You're asking how I installed the Gnome Extensions on Firefox?

Comment: no worries, I found a way to get dash to panel below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager`

Then open it from the GUI menu and adjust dash to panel as required.